# How can I change the max iOS version supported by Xcode by updating a config file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5, ios7.1, xcode5.1

So, Apple released it's iOS 7.1 recently and I stupidly updated it and now I am forced to upgrade my Xcode from 5.0 to 5.1 .

I have a release coming soon and some of the libraries are not directly compatible with Xcode 5.1 .
So I am planning to use Xcode 5.0 itself, but it will not detect the iOS 7.1 x-( .

Is there any way I can fool Xcode into believing that it should support iOS 7.1 by changing a config or an XML ?

One observation :  once I connected my iPhone with 7.1 and surprisingly it was detected by Xcode 5.0 and I happily coded for few hours, but as soon as I disconnected and reconnected it, it was never detected again by Xcode 5.0 . Can anyone explain how that happened and also, if you can tell me how to make that happen again ;-)

Comment: What kind of incompatibility are you seeing that Xcode 5.1 is not usable?

Comment: @Zaph must have had my brain switched off, thanks!